# Need alternative for reading ini-files (problems with kernel32-solution)

Tags: c#, ini, blocked

i am reading a ini-file using the Kernel32-solution (GetPrivateProfileString). It was working fine under XP but now it is (not) running under Windows-7.
Now i have the problem that windows7 protects the file and i cannot write into it (with another program).
As soon as i open the ini-file with kernel32 it is blocked forever until i close the program.
Is there any parameter to simply reading the ini- file without write-protecting it?
Or any other solutions on reading an ini-file?
I am using C# 2010 express

Thanks for help

Edit:
Meanwhile i tried to copy the original ini-file to a second-file and then i am only reading the copied ini-file with the kernel32-functions.
But now it seems that the simple copy command 
    System.IO.File.Copy(PathOriginal, lokalPath, true); 
is blocking the original file for the other program after it is copied.

So my problem is not with the ini-file now. It is file-protection in generall under windows 7.

Is there a trick to "free" the handle of the file i windows 7?

Comment: INI files are more or less deprecated now. You could try to work with configuration files, but I find them difficult to use as a readwrite source. If I need to write some app or user config I prefer to use XML files stored in the CommonApplicationData or ApplicationData

Comment: A simple search for C# ini file parser shows up plenty of possibilities. Many of these leave the file handling up to you, they just want to be passed an open stream - so you just open the stream specifying at least `FileShare.Write` and hand off to them.

Answer (score 4):

Try out [Nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net/), which is a 100% C# version (no DLL/PInvoke required).  There's a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Trove.Nini/) as well.

Example INI file:

```
[Cars]
model = Toyota
year = 2012
```

The C# code:

```
Nini.Ini.IniDocument doc = new Nini.Ini.IniDocument ("configuration.ini");
Console.WriteLine ("Model: " + doc.Get("Cars", "model"));
Console.WriteLine ("Year: " + doc.GetInt("Cars", "year"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this IniReader library. It may help you with your problem:

http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=6